# SQL Server Date Selection in Recordset based on initial date and number of days in another recordset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, resultset

What I'm about to ask about, I had difficulties what I was looking for throughout the forum postings on here, so any assistance at all will be greatly appreciated! :)

To help explain what I want, here's a little snippet of a view result-set that I'm working with:

```
CalendarDate:             WorkDay:

2014-10-03 00:00:00.000      1      
2014-10-02 00:00:00.000      1
2014-10-01 00:00:00.000      1
2014-09-30 00:00:00.000      1
2014-09-29 00:00:00.000      1
2014-09-26 00:00:00.000      1
2014-09-25 00:00:00.000      1
```

This view represents a table in our database that keeps track of actual working days for our company; this view excludes any non-working days (hence all the "1"s).

What I'm trying to do is take a datetime value from another result-set, find it in this result-set and count down the number of days (based on a value being brought in from another result-set as well). So, if I was starting with October 3, 2014 and the number of days I was going back was 5, I want to end up on September 26, 2014.

Personally, I see this being accomplished in a unique record count on a pre-sorted view, but SQL is a diverse universe of ways to do the same thing and I would like to achieve this in the most efficient way possible :).

Like I said at the beginning, I didn't know this question should be properly worded so if this is a duplicate post then I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `row_number` analytic function and then derive the difference in days

Assuming your second result set is like this

```
create table Table2
( StartDate datetime,
  days int
 );

insert into Table2 values ('2014-10-03', 5);
insert into Table2 values ('2014-10-02', 5);
```

You can join with current table with this result set and get the required out dates using cte and row_number and self join.

```
with cte 
as
(
select CalendarDate, row_number() over ( order by CalendarDate desc) as rn, WorkDay
from Table1 
)
select T1.StartDate, T1.days, T2.CalendarDate as OutDate from 
cte
join Table2 T1
on cte.calendarDate = T1.StartDate
join cte T2
on T2.rn - cte.rn = T1.days
```

result will come out like

```
STARTDATE         DAYS   OUTDATE
October, 03 2014    5   September, 26 2014 
October, 02 2014    5   September, 25 2014
```

[`SQL FIDDLE`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30b6d2/7)

Answer (score 2):

And when you use the TOP-Clause:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CalendarDate
FROM (SELECT TOP 5 CalendarDate
      FROM DateTable
      WHERE CalendarDate <'2014-10-03'
      ORDER BY CalendarDate DESC
     ) AS T5
ORDER BY CalendarDate ASC
```